# javascript requestAnimationFrame final position never exact

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

```js
let pf = document.querySelectorAll('.pf');

for (let i of pf) {
  Object.assign(i.style, {
    left: '400px'
  })
}

function shiftLetters() {
  let start = performance.now();
  let dist = -400;
  let dur = 500;

  const logoAnimate = (timestamp) => {

    var runtime = timestamp - start
    var progress = Math.min(runtime / dur, 1)
    const position = progress * dist;

    if (runtime < dur) {
      for (let i = 0; i < pf.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            pf[i].style.transform = `translate3d(${position}px,0,0)`
          }, 100 * i)
        })(i);
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(logoAnimate)
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(logoAnimate)
}

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', shiftLetters);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 10%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 10%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.pf {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: red;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="pf"></div>
  <div class="pf"></div>
  <div class="pf"></div>
  <div class="pf"></div>
</div>
<button>animate</button>
```

I have 4 elements when button is clicked their supposed to end at the exact distance of the dist variable. Instead it end at random integers and never exactly -400px like stated in in my dist variable of -400. Has to be something simple. I've written the variables outside of scope etc etc..

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you never apply the final transform. On the last iteration of `shiftLetters` when  `position` finally = -400 `runtime` is greater than `dur` so you never enter your if statement and apply the transform. Slightly refactored code below.

```js
let pf = document.querySelectorAll('.pf');

for (let i of pf) {
  Object.assign(i.style, {
    left: '400px'
  })
}

function shiftLetters() {
  let start = performance.now();
  let dist = -400;
  let dur = 500;

  const logoAnimate = (timestamp) => {

    var runtime = timestamp - start
    var progress = Math.min(runtime / dur, 1)
    const position = progress * dist;

    applyTransform(position);

    if (runtime < dur) {
      requestAnimationFrame(logoAnimate)
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(logoAnimate)
}

function applyTransform(position) {
  for (let i = 0; i < pf.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      pf[i].style.transform = `translate3d(${position}px,0,0)`
    }, 100 * i)
  }
}

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', shiftLetters);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 10%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 10%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.pf {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: red;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="pf"></div>
  <div class="pf"></div>
  <div class="pf"></div>
  <div class="pf"></div>
</div>
<button>animate</button>
```

Comment: Gotcha, when I console.log 'position' it was never the final destination. But the second to last iteration. Outside the if statement! Brilliant!